# Handling event on browser crash

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

I am using php 7 for server side and java script for interaction with twilio services for enabling video services on a website.

In one webpage I am using twilio to broadcast video service upon which status of agent is changed to active in database. I want to make sure this status is changed to paused when agent presses stop button or browser closes or crashes.

I have used window.on unload and working fine on browser page close only. I want to make sure this event is handled on browser crash also. How can I change database status upon crash/close?

Sample of code used for browser close ajax call is as under:

```
 $(window).on('unload',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(`Exit done`);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'main-vedio-agent.php',
    type: 'post',
    async:false,
    data: { "pausevedioandchatroom": "1","agentname": agentdivname},
    success: function(response) { 
      }
  });  
});
```

Comment: So you want to detect when the browser crashes?

Comment: Yes I want to make sure one ajax call is made in any case of webpage close.